# can you use canvases from different python files?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i have a canvas set up with an image and everything in file 1.py like this

```
canvassomethingimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bin/level1assets/scenes2/11.png"))
canvassomething = Canvas(root, width=1446, height=899, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvassomething.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=canvassomethingimg)
```

and want to use it in file2.py

```
canvassoemthing.place(x=-1, y=0)
```

ofcourse there's code for it to work like the root and everything and i have it. But i need to start using canvases from a different file. Is it possible?

Comment: Definitely, it's possible but you have to make sure to have a canvas class (a class that inherits Canvas) or class with the canvas as it's elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which file is you main entry point for your program.

- If it's file1.py, then file2.py should probably be a collections of functions/classes that can be used in file1.py, and use your created canvas as a parameter.

file2.py:

```
def place_canvas(canvas):
    canvas.place(x=-1, y=0)
```

file1.py

```
from file2 import place_canvas

canvassomethingimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bin/level1assets/scenes2/11.png"))
canvassomething = Canvas(root, width=1446, height=899, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvassomething.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=canvassomethingimg)
...
place_canvas(canvassomething)
```

- Now if it's the opposite (you only want to initialise some stuff in file1 and run the main logic in file2), you can use an initialise function in file1 that returns a Canvas object and use it in file2:

file1.py

```
def init_canvas():
    ... # Probably the rest of your initialisation (like defining `root`)
    canvas_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bin/level1assets/scenes2/11.png"))
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=1446, height=899, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=canvassomethingimg)
    return canvas
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import init_canvas

canvassomething = init_canvas()
canvassomething.place(x=-1, y=0)
```